# How to install CentOS 7 to a USB stick using manual partitioning

Tags: installer-anaconda

In the installation UI for CentOS7, when I manually partition a USB stick, I get the error message "There is no bootable device and no boot partition", although I have explicitly assigned a /boot as a standard (non LVM) partition. It doesn't let me get past this, and as a result I cannot install CentOS.

But, if instead I choose "Automatic Partitioning" on the USB stick, the installation proceeds without error.

Under the manual partitioning mode, I don't see any options for assigning a bootable partition. Is this a bug in Anaconda, or am I missing something here?

EDIT:
The exact error is: "you have not created a bootloader stage1 target device. You have not created a bootable partition."

Answer (score 0):

I let the system do it's Automatic Partitioning, and took a look at what it did. As it turns out, it created both a /boot_efi and a /boot partition. The partition table shows the first as type "EFI System", it's formatted as vfat, and the second as an XFS filesystem. I wiped the system and created these manually and it works.

So, there isn't a bug or anything broken. It's just a matter of giving it an EFI partition (at least on my laptop.)